calico resource mapping not found for kind "GlobalNetworkPolicy" in version "projectcalico.org/v3"
I have a kubernetes cluster with calico installed (helm chart version v3.28.0). I have already applied multiple times calico networkpolicies. All of a sudden, applying the exact same policy gives me this error:
$ kubectl apply -f my-policy.yaml
error: resource mapping not found for name: "my-policy" namespace: "" from "my-policy.yaml": no matches for kind "GlobalNetworkPolicy" in version "projectcalico.org/v3"
ensure CRDs are installed first

How come this doesn't work anymore?

You can check if the api-resources still exist:
kubectl api-resources --api-group=projectcalico.org -o wide

If the output is empty, this means that kubernetes doesn't know about these resources (anymore). To ensure kubernetes detects these api-resources again:
kubectl delete apiservices.apiregistration.k8s.io v3.projectcalico.org
kubectl rollout restart deployment calico-apiserver

